# clustering sets of numbers

Tags: clustering, algorithms

I have some experimental measurements which come in sets $S_i$.  Each $S_i$ contains some floating point numbers $s_{ij}$.  I think the $S_i$ form clusters with similar contents.  How do I assign the $S_i$ to clusters and estimate the number of clusters $n$?

Some details:

- I do not know what distribution $s_{ij}$ is sampled from, but I strongly suspect it depends on $i$ and not $j$.  It's probably not a symmetric distribution.
- All I know about $n$ is that it is bigger than one.
- The $S_i$ are different sizes.  Some may be too small to be useful.  I do not mind discarding them.
- $S_i$ happens to be an ordered set.  I could use algorithms that work with ordered sets, but I think this is unnecessary.

I am looking for suggestions of algorithms or categories of algorithms I might use.

I think this must be a well-known problem, but I do not know what it is called.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no unique solution to a clustering problem, and neither to the number of clusters problem. You will need to specify what kind of clusters you need and for what aim. A general approach is to define a distance measure between the $S_i$ and to run a standard distance-based clustering method. The Average Silhouette Width is one option then to say something about the number of clusters. However this depends on the specification of distance, and this, and also whether the approach is any good, depends on your clustering aim.

Comment: The distance needs to formalise what it means for sets to be similar or dissimilar in the situation in question. This can only be specified appropriately understanding the subject matter, which I don't. There are many possibilities. Just one example, you can compute the average difference (absolute values) from any number in one set to any number on the other set. I don't have the slightest idea whether this makes sense here, but maybe you can use it as a starting point - figuring out in what way it is inappropriate may give you an idea to improve it.

Comment: @ChristianHennig "compute the average difference (absolute values) from any number in one set to any number on the other set" Seems like a better approach than any I had thought of.  Any thoughts about estimating n once I have done that?

Comment: I had already mentioned the Average Silhouette Width, also referred to as Silhouette index, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering) Once more not really understanding your application, I have no idea whether this is any good for you, but it is a possibility.